# xml signing with google-cloud-kms in java/kotlin

Tags: java, xml, digital-signature, private-key, google-cloud-kms

I don't understand how I would use the built in xml signing library in java with google kms. I have my pub/private key in google kms.

I do the following without google kms:

```
val keyPair = getKeyPair() //get the keypair from my local file system
val dsc = DOMSignContext(keyPair.private, w3cDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("MY_ELEMENT_TO_INSERT").first())
val xmlSignatureFactory = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM")
val xmlSignature = xmlSignatureFactory.newXMLSignature(signedInfo, keyInfo)
xmlSignature.sign(dsc)
```

If you notice I have to give DOMSignContext a private key. It also takes a keyselector, but we run into the same problem.

My problem is that google-cloud-kms does not allow to get the private key, seems like I can only encrypt using keyManagementServiceClient.asymmetricSign which allows me to pass data I want to encrypt to google kms.

**Am I not understanding something or is it impossible to use google kms with the xml signing library?**

Comment: Instead of using the private key directly with DOMSignContext, you'll need to use Google KMS's asymmetricSign method to perform the signing operation.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you cannot directly use the private key from [Google Cloud KMS](https://cloud.google.com/security/products/security-key-management?hl=en) as you would with a local key pair to integrate it with the Java XML signing library: Google Cloud KMS is designed to keep the private key... *private*, by not exposing it directly.
Instead, you might have you to perform the cryptographic operations through the [KMS API](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/reference/rest), where the signing operation happens in the cloud, and only the signature is returned.

That would mean adjusting your signing process to use Google Cloud KMS's [`asymmetricSign` method](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.keyRings.cryptoKeys.cryptoKeyVersions/asymmetricSign) for the signing step.

```bash
Local System                           Google Cloud KMS
     |                                      |
     |---(1) Prepare data to sign --------->|
     |                                      |
     |---(2) Request signature ------------>|
     |                                      |
     |<--(3) Receive signature--------------|
     |                                      |
```

To implement this with your XML signing, you would:

- generate the digest of the data you intend to sign.
- use the `asymmetricSign` method of Google Cloud KMS to sign the digest.
- insert the received signature back into your XML document.

```kotlin
import com.google.cloud.kms.v1.KeyManagementServiceClient
import com.google.cloud.kms.v1.AsymmetricSignRequest
import com.google.cloud.kms.v1.Digest
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString
import java.security.MessageDigest
// Import other necessary libraries

fun signXmlWithKms(w3cDoc: Document) {
    // Assume MY_ELEMENT_TO_INSERT contains the data you want to sign
    val dataToSign = // Extract the data from w3cDoc that needs to be signed
    
    // Convert data to sign to a digest
    val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
    val digestBytes = md.digest(dataToSign.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))
    
    // Prepare request for Google Cloud KMS
    val digest = Digest.newBuilder().setSha256(ByteString.copyFrom(digestBytes)).build()
    val asymmetricSignRequest = AsymmetricSignRequest.newBuilder()
        .setName("projects/[PROJECT_ID]/locations/[LOCATION]/keyRings/[KEY_RING]/cryptoKeys/[KEY]/cryptoKeyVersions/[VERSION]")
        .setDigest(digest)
        .build()

    // Use KeyManagementServiceClient to sign the digest
    KeyManagementServiceClient.create().use { client ->
        val response = client.asymmetricSign(asymmetricSignRequest)
        val signature = response.signature.toByteArray()
        
        // Insert the signature back into your XML in the appropriate place
        // That part depends on your XML structure and how you intend to include the signature
    }
}
```

But: that does modify the flow of data signing to involve a *remote* call to Google Cloud KMS: depending on your use case, the performance might be affected.